# Why does exporting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS not work with `bq`?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

The [google docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/latest/gcloud-auth.html) say to export the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path to a service account's JSON key, and gcloud will use it. I can't get it to work.

My command is:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/ubuntu/.config/google-creds.json bq ls
```

This just brings up an error:

> You do not currently have an active account selected. Please run:
>
> $ gcloud auth login
>
> to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
>   different account:
>
> $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
>
> to select an already authenticated account to use.

`gcloud -v` gives:

```
Google Cloud SDK 92.0.0

bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2016.01.12
core-nix 2015.11.24
gcloud
gsutil 4.16
gsutil-nix 4.15
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this? I need `gsutil` and `bq` to use this file. I'm working with multiple projects so can't activate any one in particular.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)?:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file google-creds.json
```

(It seems the command-line tools don't go down the whole credential discovery chain, as gcloud does when it's being used as a library in code.)

---

If you have several configurations (eg auth, project ids) that you need to use, you can set up [configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations). For example, if you have two service account credentials you'd like to use - call them `sa1.json` and `sa2.json` - you can do something like:

```
$ gcloud config configurations create proj1
$ gcloud config configurations activate proj1
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file sa1.json

$ gcloud config configurations create proj2
$ gcloud config configurations activate proj2
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file sa2.json
```

Now, you can either use the `gcloud config configurations activate` command to set the configuration you'd like to use, or set the `CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME` environment variable to specify under which configuration you'd like to run a command. ie to run `bq ls` using the `sa1.json` cred:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=proj1 bq ls
```

and for the `sa2.json` cred:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=proj2 bq ls
```

Comment: Yes but see my other question for background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883810/how-to-authenticate-google-apis-with-different-service-account-credentials I thought this would be a simpler solution.

Comment: Ah - what you're looking for is `gcloud config configurations`. I'll elaborate in the actual answer.